# Inno Setup - How to localize a string in Pascal Script?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How to change the `'Next'` with a language? It is possible?

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = iscustompage1.id then
    starttimer(WizardForm.Handle,WizardForm.NEXTBUTTON.Handle,'Next',5)
  else
  if (CurPageID = wpWelcome) or (CurPageID = wpSelectDir) then
  begin
    stoptimer();
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To localize a string for Pascal Script, define a [custom message](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection) in the language file:

```
[CustomMessages]
NextButtonCaption=Next
```

And then use this custom message using the [`CustomMessage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_custommessage) function in your code:

```pascal
starttimer(
  WizardForm.Handle, WizardForm.NEXTBUTTON.Handle, 
  CustomMessage('NextButtonCaption'), 5)
```