# How to translate information on a custom page created using CreateInputOptionPage

Tags: inno-setup

I have this below snippet in my script, I want to translate this to different language supported by my application. I looked at this solution but this doesn't seem to work in my case as this is for message box [how-to-translate-texts-contained-in-msgbox-in-inno-setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519174/how-to-translate-texts-contained-in-msgbox-in-inno-setup)

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
var doPrint:boolean; 
begin
  { Create the pages }
    UsagePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpLicense,
    'MyApp setup information', 'How would you like to install MyApp?',
    'Please specify how you would like to install MyApp, then click Next.',
    True, False);
  UsagePage.Add('As service (Recommended)');
  UsagePage.Add('Without service');
  UsagePage.Values[0] := true;
   {Add print button}

 doPrint:=letsPrint();

end;
```

I would like to translate this message :

```
'MyApp setup information', 'How would you like to install MyApp?',
        'Please specify how you would like to install MyApp, then click Next.
```

and the options:

```
UsagePage.Add('As service (Recommended)');
UsagePage.Add('Without service');
```

Please provide me the guidance on this.

Comment: See [Inno Setup - How to localize a string in Pascal Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41185761/850848)

Comment: Thanks for the quick advise @MartinPrikryl, I'm going to try this and will update the post accordingly.

Comment: Working perfect!! thank you so much.